# checkout code from SVN repository gives error in xcode 5

Tags: ios, svn, xcode5

I am trying to checkout code from SVN repository, which fails giving below error after providing the credentials and Repository address.

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

And below in the console :

> IDESourceControlAuthentication: Couldn't remove password from
>   keychain: Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-25300 "The specified
>   item could not be found in the keychain." UserInfo=0x7fe7f5320860
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The specified item could not be found in the
>   keychain.}

Note that it was working fine up to Xcode 4.6 and started giving me error after updating to Xcode 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect once using command line tools and accept server certificate permanently. You won't have any problems afterwards.

Just run an svn command like svn info and you should see sth like below

svn info https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/xtext-utils/subprojects/unittesting/branches

> Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.codespot.com:443':
>
> - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
>
>   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
>
> Certificate information:
>
> - Hostname: *.googlecode.com
> - Valid: from Wed, 16 Feb 2011 00:27:28 GMT until Thu, 16 Feb 2012 00:37:28 GMT
> - Issuer: Google Inc, US
> - Fingerprint: 34:4b:90:e7:e3:36:81:0d:52:1f:10:c0:4c:98:66:90:4a:9e:05:c9
>
> (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?

Accept permanently or temporarily to continue.

However I strongly recommend any other subversion client application or command line tools which are much more reliable compared to Xcode.